# Unit testing queries with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing

I'm currently building a rest api and I'm struggling to find the best way to unit test each route.

A route handler performs various things and one of them is to execute a query to mongodb. I can unit test the route handler by using stubs, but if I'm testing the query I cannot stub the query itself, I need to have an in-memory mongodb that I could reset and insert new data for each test.

How do you test queries? I'm thinking that the only real way to ensure that the query does what I need is to use a real mongodb database installed in the testing machine (typically in the same machine used for developing).

Comment: If anyone is interested: [mongodb-fixture](https://github.com/gagle/node-mongodb-fixture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, just as for relation databases, you need to have real base. if mongo offers in-memory auto-created version then it's easy. if not, then each developer has to have running mongo before he runs integration tests. for CI you can have one single dedicated mongo but than you have to prevent concurrent access (schema creation, multiple transactions etc). you should also implement automatic creation of schema if needed and empty database before each test. in relational db rollback is usually enough. when it's not enough then trimming all tables helps. although we had to implement it manually as we couldn't find any existing tools